# regex question php preg_match

Tags: php, regex

trying to match the following:

rawurl="http://www.domain.com/page/etc/"

the URL itself is variable and could contain all sorts! ? querystrings and more.
Is there an escape function to make it regex safe?

so I have this so far

```
            $var is already defined..
            $url = "www.adomain.com/with/extras/"
            $url = str_replace(" \/ ","/",$url);  // maybe more needed here. 
            $pattern = "/rawurl\=\"http\:\/\/$url/";                
            preg_match($pattern, $var, $out);
```

having problems formatting the regex correctly, have been going cross eyed now for several hours. Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at [**preg_quote**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)

Comment: How have I missed that function for so long?